# New to unit testing, would like some input on this unit test

Tags: unit-testing

I'm fairly new to unit-testing and would like some input on good test implementations on some functions I have.

For methods that takes some input, and return an output, without knowing the expected return value, how would I properly test it? I have an example below...

```
int add(int a, int b) {
     return a + b;
}

int actual = add(1,2);
int expect = 1 + 2; 

TEST_ASERT_EQUAL_INT(expect, actual);
```

Assuming I'm naive and does not know `1 + 2 = 3`. Would performing the same arithmetic as the function i'm testing to get the expected value consider good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: No.

Your expectation should be hard in the code and not calculated somehow, two points here:

1. If you recreate the complex calculation in your test code, you dont have a "stupid enough" test that you can really verify that the result is as expected
2. If you use the SUT (System Under Test) to generate the calculated / expected value in the test, you are still not testing that your expectations actually occur.

My recommendation is to always expect fixed values. Now in the example of `1 + 2 = 3` this is straight forward and you would just write your test in a way that you set `int expected = 3`.

However, as you mentioned already it might be a bit more complex operation like creating a hash or something. In that case I recommend you follow three steps to ensure that your SUT does what it is supposed to do:

1. Generate a output value with your SUT
2. Verify (e.g. by hand, or however else you would manually do that) the correctness of this value
3. If(!) step 2 works out, use this value as your fixed expectation in your unit test.

Do this a couple of times (meaning use different input/output values) and you can make pretty damn sure that your SUT does what it should do.